# Explanation for relationship between hypotenuse segments and leg lengths?

Tags: geometry, conjectures

```
   |`
   | `  x
   |  `
   |   ` c
a  | z /`  
   |  /  ` y
   |_/    `
   |/|_____`

       b
```

I'm new to this SE, but I have an SO account, so hello!

Assume that z is the altitude that intersects the hypotenuse, and x and y are the resulting line segments. This is what my friend had to say about this.

$$ z = \sqrt{xy} $$

You cannot find $z$ with $a$ and $b$.

Here's what I said.

Somehow, $a$ and $b$ must be related to $x$ and $y$. At first I thought that $$\frac{a}{a+b} * c = x$$
That was wrong, as the altitude did not bisect the right angle.
Through some thinking, but not proving, I said this, which was correct, AFAIK.

$$\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2} * c = x\\\\\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2} * c = y $$
Some simplifying ensued.
$$\frac{a^2}{c^2} * c = x\\\\\frac{b^2}{c^2} * c = y $$
More.
$$\frac{a^2}{c} = x\\\\\frac{b^2}{c} = y $$

Now that $a$ and $b$ were used to find $x$ and $y$, I got $z$ with the geometric mean.

$$ z = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{c} * \frac{b^2}{c}} $$
That goes to:
$$ z = \frac{ab}{c} $$

This was all and well, but then I was asked how did you come up with the first step?

Comment: For a quicker route to the relation $zc = ab$, simply compute twice the area of the triangle in two ways: "base $\times$ height" using (1) a leg as the base, and (2) the hypotenuse as the base.

Comment: I see, I used that method alongside that to as reconfirmation that $zc = ab$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\area}{\operatorname{Area}}$
As usual, let $A,B,C$ be the vertices opposing the sides $a,b$ and $c$, respectively. Let $Z$ be the remaining vertex (i.e. where the altitude intersects the hypothenuse).

Then, you will notice that $$\frac{x}{c}=\frac{\area(\triangle ZBC)}{\area(\triangle ABC)}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{y}{c}=\frac{\area(\triangle AZC)}{\area(\triangle ABC)}.$$ This is because these triangles have the altitude $ZC$ in common. Therefore, their areas are proportional to the remaining sides.

But the areas of the three similar right triangles are proportional to the areas of the squares over their hypothenuses. This yields $$\frac{\area(\triangle ZBC)}{\area(\triangle ABC)}=\frac{a^2}{c^2}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\area(\triangle AZC)}{\area(\triangle ABC)}=\frac{b^2}{c^2}.$$ Observing that $c^2=a^2+b^2$ now yields your "problem part".